# Enumerating chemical graphs

Tags: graph-theory, chemistry

I would like to make and **visualize** graph library of $n$ vertices that each vertex can only have maximum of four edges. The reason behind this is that the results will be used for designing chemical libraries where each vertex is a carbon and a carbon can only form from one to four lines (edges) to carbon(s), neglecting any other atom (for example, hydrogen) connecting to the carbon. **In short, this library will consist of pure carbon network.**

I appreciate any result that chemically unfeasible because considering this aspect is irrelevant in this forum. What softwares that can be used to exhaustively enumerate the graphs? It would also be good if there is any resource which has realized this idea.

Thank you.

Comment: Alkanes only or what?

Comment: A small piece of code suffices for this task. You can try enumerating the first few cases and consult OEIS for more info.

Comment: Should I have to do it, I would begin by considering quad-trees (trees where each node has at most four children) "grafted" afterwards the ones on the others (with a possible chemical interpretation ?) The risk is to miss some graphs but as combinatorial explosion will soon come... (for example, with $n=10$, I bet that there are many thousand solutions...)

Comment: If you work with Python, here is a possible [library](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/tutorial.html)

Comment: You can use [nauty](https://pallini.di.uniroma1.it) to generate graphs.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel I am interested in alkanes only at now but it would be interesting if alkene graphs can also be made.

Comment: You need to look at CAGE (https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~CaGe/) and associated documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia: Chemical graph generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_graph_generator)

[Wikipedia: List of straight-chain alkanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_straight-chain_alkanes)

Computer algebra systems like MAPLE and MATHEMATICA can generate random graphs with given properties like connectedness, absence of cycles and vertex degree.

[Chemistry Development Kit](https://cdk.github.io/)

[Peironcely, J. E.; Rojas-Chertó, M.; Fichera, D.; Reijmers, Th.; Coulier, L.; Faulon, J.-L.; Hankemeier, Th.: OMG: Open Molecule Generator. J. Cheminform. 4 (2012) 21](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3558358/)

[Fiehn Lab: Molecular Isomer Generators. 2016](https://fiehnlab.ucdavis.edu/projects/seven-golden-rules/molecular-isomer-generator)

[Yirik, M. A.; Steinbeck, Ch.: Chemical graph generators. PLOS Computational Biology 17 (2021) (1) e1008504](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7785115/)
[Yirik, M. A.: Development of an Open Source Molecular Structure Generator](https://www.researchgate.net/project/Development-of-an-Open-Source-Molecular-Structure-Generator)
https://github.com/MehmetAzizYirik
https://github.com/MehmetAzizYirik/AlgorithmicGroupTheory

You could use the method of systematic generation of the graphs of given height used by Cayley, Pólya and Read:
Pólya, G.: Kombinatorische Anzahlbestimmungen für Gruppen, Graphen und chemische Verbindungen. Acta Mathematica 68 (1937) 145-254
Pólya, G; Read, R. C.: Combinatorial Enumeration of Groups, Graphs, and Chemical Compounds. Springer, 1987
Read, R.C.: The Enumeration of Acyclic Chemical Compounds. in: Balaban, A.T. (Ed.): Chemical Applications of Graph Theory. Academic Press, 1976

OEIS: A000055 Number of trees with n unlabeled nodes

Answer (score 1):

For just alkanes, the suggestions in the comments are perfectly fine (nAUTy, for example). If you want more then I would suggest one of the programs on this list:

https://fiehnlab.ucdavis.edu/projects/seven-golden-rules/molecular-isomer-generator

or, for a more recent example, there is MAYGEN:

https://github.com/MehmetAzizYirik/MAYGEN

note that these are isomer generators (just the graph skeleton of the molecule) and do not generate stereoisomers. As you mention, no attempt is made to make 'realistic' molecules, in terms of energy or synthetic reality.

Answer (score 1):

This looks very nice and fast:

https://github.com/takemaru/graphillion#graphillion---fast-lightweight-library-for-a-huge-number-of-graphs